# red cross mysql with MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm running MariaDB database and all columns have a red cross:

[image: MariaDB Issues]

When importing databases I get the following error:

> Fout
>   SQL-query:
>
> /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
>
> MySQL meldt: Documentatie
>    #1231 - Variable 'collation_connection' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

Comment: The error would indicate that you don't have a valid value set for `@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION`

Answer (score 0):

### image/red crosses

Can you please tell us, which client you are using?
Can you please try a describe of that table, `describe artikelen;`?
I expect that some of your scripts contain errors, now columns do not exist anymore while the client is caching that information (see next section)

### Import error

I assume that you have a comma somewhere in your import script where no comma should be before the line `/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;` or a missing semicolon.

Comment: I use chrome as a client. So I tried IE and i had no cross any more, so I delete all the cache from chrome. It's working again. I've deleted the  /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

fromt the sql file and it seems working. Thanks!!